# How to input a range of dates and turn it into a list?

Tags: python

I would like to be able to just input a range of dates rather than every single date as i'd like to do some time series work on this data. Here is my code so far:

```
import re

def date():   
    dates = []
    user_input =''
    pattern = re.compile('\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{2}')
    while user_input != 'end':
        user_input =raw_input("Please put folder with format yy.mm.dd or 'end': ")
        if pattern.match(user_input):
            dates.append(user_input)
        elif user_input == 'end':
            print 'Dates:'
        else:
            print "Use yy.mm.dd format or write 'end'" 
    return dates
```

Comment: Please let us know what is currently going wrong with your code.

Comment: don't bother using re, just try converting to datetime objects using a try/except if you want to use the dates . 44.44.44 will also match your regex

Comment: in the code just missing `import re` and call function `date()` .... down vote

Comment: currently it works but I would need to type in each individual day. I would like to be able to just put in a range of date and have the function fill a list of those dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using datetime if you want to work with dates, as it is your regex will match any combination of dd.dd.dd:

```
from datetime import datetime
def date():
    dates = []
    user_input =''
    while user_input != 'end':
        user_input = raw_input("Please put folder with format yy.mm.dd or 'end': ")
        try:
            dte = datetime.strptime(user_input,"%y.%m.%d")
            dates.append(dte)
        except ValueError:
            print "Use yy.mm.dd format or write 'end'"
    print 'Dates:'
    return dates
```

If you want a range of dates between start and end:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
def date():
    dates = []
    while True:
        start = raw_input("Please put start date with format yy.mm.dd or 'end': ")
        if start == "end":
            break
        end = raw_input("Please put end date with format yy.mm.dd or 'end': ")
        try:
            start =  datetime.strptime(start,"%y.%m.%d")
            end =  datetime.strptime(end,"%y.%m.%d")
            for _ in xrange((end-start).days+1):
                dates.append(start)
                start += timedelta(days=1)
        except ValueError:
            print "Use yy.mm.dd format or write 'end'"
    print 'Dates:'
    return dates
```

[pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#generating-ranges-of-timestamps) may also be useful:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
def date():
    dates = []
    while True:
        start = raw_input("Please put start date with format yy.mm.dd or 'end': ")
        if start == "end":
            break
        end = raw_input("Please put end date with format yy.mm.dd or 'end': ")
        try:
            start = datetime.strptime(start,"%y.%m.%d")
            end = datetime.strptime(end,"%y.%m.%d")
            dates.append(pd.date_range(start, end))
        except ValueError:
            print "Use yy.mm.dd format or write 'end'"
    print 'Dates:'
    return dates
```

Comment: that is definitely a better way to have dates inputted, what I would like to be able to do is input '15.04.15-15.04.20' and have an array ['15.04.15','15.04.16'...'15.04.20'] be produced.

Comment: @bpr, then get a start and end date and increase using a timedelta. I edited the answer

Comment: no prob,  I added a pandas method also as it may be in line with what you want to do.